# What types of discovery are there and how do I share them?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

[image]

I was playing Black Flag Singleplayer while being with a friend on Teamspeak, who is also my friend on UPlay and he was playing Black Flag at the very same time. After a while he mentioned that I shared a chest with him and how I did it. Fact is, I do not now how I activated it. The chest (blue on the map) held 1000 Reales for each of us. There is also an achievement for doing this.

So how do I share those things and what types of discoveries are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 discoveries:

1. White Whale - A white whale to be hunted.
2. Royal Convoy - a Convoy with 5000$ on the main sheep, as oposed to normal convoys that have 2000$.
3. Community Treasure Chests, just like normal treasure chests, only with more money and can pop anywhere (or from a pool of possible spawning places).

You don't need to share them manually, they will automatically be shared with your PSN network/x-box live/UPlay friends, and will show you a pop-up informing you of those. All you need to do is be online.

You don't have to have friends, even if you don't have friends on your account, you'll get the discoveries, the rewards and the achievement associate with them.

You can also disable those events if you want, and disable getting notifications when your friends find them.

Comment: For the record, you don't need to have friends to find and share the discoveries. You only need to be online

Answer (score 3):

Sharing is done automatically as soon as you discover something that can be shared. You **have to be online during your discovery**.

There are only 3 types of shareable discoveries so far, **all of which are blue on the map**:

- Special Chests
- White Whales
- Royal Convoys

You do not need to loot/hunt them, just find them. The places they appear in seem to be pre-defined. However, they are somewhat rare and appear at random.

You should easily encounter all 3 of them naturally as you progress through the story. Keep in mind that White Whales and Royal Convoys can only be discovered at sea, meaning you'll have to actually sail, rather than use Fast Travel.